# C++ Compiler Is Not Recognised After Full Installation

Tags: c++, compiler-errors, window

I am trying to run C++ code on my OS (Windows 10). I installed MSYS2 and followed its instructions (using pacman to install gcc). The problem is after this step, when i type gcc --version i still get "gcc: command not found".

I added "C:\msys64\mingw32\bin" to my user variable's Path and ran the command again and i still get the same error.
I am totaly confused here. Does anyone have any suggestion?

Thanks

Comment: Try logout/login, then it should work.

Comment: @Jabberwocky Yes, that is what i meant. What should i log out from? My account?

Comment: A simple reboot can help with any environment variables that are only set when logging in.

Comment: @eh329 yes, logout from your Windows account. Reboot will work as well, but that's overkill.

Comment: @tadman Done that, does not work.

Comment: @Jabberwocky Tried both. They do not work.

Comment: You'll need to track down where `gcc.exe` is. Remember you can use [Visual Studio](https://visualstudio.microsoft.com) which has an integrated compiler.

Comment: If you still get that error after: ***I added "C:\msys64\mingw32\bin" to my user variable's Path and ran the command again and i still get the same error.*** Then for some reason either you did not install MinGW using msys2 or it failed or your `PATH` setting was wrong or is not applied to whatever command prompt you are typing in. You will have to 1. Look for `gcc.exe` and verify that it is located where you told your OS to look. 2. Check the `PATH` environment variable in the shell that you are using to see if the `PATH` you typed is actually being used.

Comment: [msys2 + gcc installation instructions that you have to work at to get wrong](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30071634/4581301) And a tactical note: Adding the compiler to the path will become a problem in the future if you find yourself having to use multiple gcc compilers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suppose, for gcc on Windows you need download from sourceforge.net and run mingw-get-setup.exe

Comment: I would recommend against the sourceforge downloads. The MinGW version on sourceforge.net is usually very old. If you instead use msys2 you get the current MinGW with gcc-12.2 and also it contains a very good package management tool `pacman` and several thousand open source libraries that you can easily install using a 1 line install command.

Comment: @drescherjm Oddly enough, this is the only recommendation that worked.

Comment: I still recommend you checking and understanding why the path of the executable was not found. Using a 6 to 10 year old version of g++ will limit what projects you can build.

Comment: @eh329 You will find that in the wonderful world of just about everything a lot of bad ideas sort of work.